# Is there a syntax for conditional template interpolation?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an angular (2.4.9) template with the following element:

```
<div *ngIf="a || b || c || d || e">Remaining</div>
```

I'm now faced with the need to change that hitherto static "Remaining" text based on another condition:

```
<div *ngIf="a || b || c || d || e || Z != 'draft'">Initial</div>
<div *ngIf="a || b || c || d || e || Z == 'draft'">Remaining</div>
```

The `*ngIf` is already loaded, and I'd like to prevent having to duplicate it, as I did in the example above, just to add that one extra condition.

I would also like to avoid doing this:

```
<div *ngIf="a || b || c || d || e">
    <div *ngIf="Z != 'draft'">Initial</div>
    <div *ngIf="Z == 'draft'">Remaining</div>
</div>
```

...because this changes the structure of the page and thus the style rules.

So, rather than introduce a new element within the div with its own `*ngIf`, which would cause us to add style rules, I was looking for something like a conditional interpolation syntax, such that I could write

```
<div *ngIf="many || conditions">{{ status === "DRAFT" ? 'Initial' : 'Remaining' }}</div>
```

in a similar way that you can do `{{ 1 + 1 }}`, which is also an expression which returns a value, so seems *at least conceptually similar*.

My attempt above causes the template parser to explode with an unmatched tag somewhere seemingly unrelated to this template, so what it's actually doing is not immediately apparent, but it's obviously incorrect.

Comment: This should work. I found a similiar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312626/angularjs-set-button-text-based-on-condition-in-ng-repeat

Comment: I don't get what you try to accomplish. Depending on whether `many` or `conditions` is true, what should happen?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That's shorthand, it's because there are 8 conditions in that `*ngIf` that control whether "Remaining" is shown. *Now* I have a new requirement to conditionally show "Remaining" or "Initial" based on additional criterion. So I don't want to duplicate the outer `*ngIf` and add this new condition, basically.

Comment: I don't really get it, but there is nothing Angular provides. If you want a condition you can use `*ngIf` to add/remove the element or if you want a conditional value than add the condition to the expression (pure TS).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Let me update the question.

Comment: Actually in Angular 4 there is `*ngIf="many || conditions as user`, then you can use `user` in the expression, but in your example I don't see what that buys you because the expression in `{{...}}` won't be executed when `*ngIf="..."` is false, therefore you **always** know it's true inside `{{...}}`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Turns out this works just fine, I had a template error elsewhere (d'oh!) but I'm open to commentary about actually doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Angular4 you can use else

```
<template #other>
  <div>Remaining</div>
</template>

<div *ngIf="a || b || c || d || e || Z != 'draft'; else other">Initial</div>
```

There is nothing for Angular2, except moving the expression to a getter or method and use that getter in `*ngIf="..."`

Comment: Very cool, thank you. I'll surely use this elsewhere!

Answer (score 0):

I had another error in my template. My example code would have worked just fine, as RemyaJ illustrated.

Comment: You can also use `<ng-container *ngIf"...">` to avoid changing the structure ("...because this changes the structure of the page")

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I also did not know about this. Thanks!